# plotcap libraries

Tags: software-installation, libraries, gnuplot

In order to install SUPREM III software the prerequisite is that plotcap libraries must be installed including libgplot.a, libhigh2.a, and libgplotF77.a.
May i know from where to download these files and how to install them?

Comment: My *guess* is you will need to build them from the [Plotcap Release 9016](http://www-tcad.stanford.edu/oldftp_sw/Pisces/plotcap.9016.tar.Z) tarball that's listed under **Support Programs** on the Stanford [TCAD webpage](http://www-tcad.stanford.edu/tcad/programs/oldftpable.html)

Comment: Check out getting the Linux patches first, that site's link is just a Verizon login page.

Comment: I did download the  Plotcap Release 9016 from Stanford TCAD webpage...may i know how to proceed further?

Comment: I couldn't get any information on Linux patches from the Verizon login page..

Comment: suprem/Plot - This directory contains the plotting compatability files. These should only be used if the Plotcap library are not available. It is STRONGLY advised that Plotcap be used instead of these files. They have mentioned this in the README file...so software should be installed even if the Plotcap Libraries are not there.

Comment: I m able to run the Makefile for Genii but when i use the Make command for setup, it results in the following error...                                                       anala@anala-Lenovo-G580:~/Desktop/Release/src/setup$ make
loading...
setup.o: In function `MAIN__':
setup.f:(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `fdate_'
opnfl-L.o: In function `opnfl_':
opnfl-L.f:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `geten_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:34: recipe for target '../../run/setup' failed
make: *** [../../run/setup] Error 1

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 2 years.